# Origen de la expresión "hacer pucheros"

Tags: expresiones, significado

Como padre suelo usar a menudo la expresión *[hacer pucheros](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1283&bih=1090&q=hacer%20pucheros&oq=hacer%20pucheros)*. Se entiende como *[puchero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYtBmHW)* en este caso:

> 4. m. coloq. Gesto o movimiento que precede al llanto verdadero o fingido. U. m. en pl. *Empezó a hacer pucheros.*

Esta acepción viene recogida en el mapa de diccionarios desde su primera edición (1780), en la que significaba exactamente lo mismo que hoy día. Así que me preguntaba cuál podría ser el origen de la expresión. He visto un par de ideas, la primera [muy descabellada](http://queviral.com/el-origen-de-la-expresion-hacer-pucheros/) a mi parecer:

> [...] La teoría más extendida es que en el Imperio Romano estas ollas se levantaban por las asas para moverlas de lugar estando calientes por lo que provocaban quemaduras y lágrimas en los portadores. Algo parecido sucedía con los niños, ya que los adultos solían besar a los niños levantándolos por las orejas –como si éstas fueran las asas del puchero– provocando, obviamente, el dolor y llanto el los pequeños.

Y la segunda con [algo más de sentido común](http://www.esacademic.com/dic.nsf/sp_sp_dichos_refranes/1139/hacer):

> El origen de la locución podría estar en los hipos y ruidos que se hacen cuando se está a punto de llorar, similares a los que salen de un puchero cuando la comida que está dentro cuece.

Sin embargo, no dejan de ser teorías y suposiciones. ¿Alguien tiene alguna referencia legítima acerca del origen de dicha expresión?

Comment: Como dicho popular, no existe una referencia legítima. ¿Cuál puede ser fiable? ¿Un diccionario de expresiones populares por internet? . Es imposible saber. ¿Qué considerarías legítima? No existe diccionario oficial, y aunque lo hubiese... no podríamos estar seguros de la elección tampoco.

Comment: Es cierto que existe una alta probabilidad de que la pregunta no tenga respuesta, pero no por ello debemos dejar de buscar. Es posible que en algún momento del pasado, cuando la expresión se popularizó, alguien dejara constancia del símil utilizado en algún escrito y por ahí se pueda determinar el origen.

Answer (score 3):

[**Covarrubias**](https://books.google.es/books?id=K10MJdL7pGIC&dq=covarrubias&pg=RA17-PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false) recoge en la pág. 598:

> "PVCHERO, la olla en que se cozian las puches. **Hazer pucheritos, es de los niños, quando quieren llorar: porque hinchan los carrillejos, a modo del puchero que es ventricoso.** Comer su puchero, contentarse con su passada."

[image]

Comment: Pensé que la imagen con el texto original de Covarrubias y la ortografía original hacia más interesante la respuesta.... si no te gusta o crees que desvirtúa tu aporte, la puedes quitar sin problemas.... yo no me enojo por esas cosas jaja.  Las respuestas son de todos para mejorarlas y aportar, pero de todas formas creo que el autor original tiene mas "derechos" que el resto de la comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Conozco esta otra teoría, tampoco tiene mucho soporte pero me parece más verosímil que la de las orejas de los niños romanos.

Los **abucheos** antiguamente eran los "griteríos", por evolución de onomatopeyas de caza como *¡uch!* y *¡hucho!* Cuando el niño estiraba la trompa y humedecía los ojitos, estaba "anunciando un abucheo". Por metonimia, el significado de la palabra pasó de lo anunciado al anuncio. Y por atracción paronímica, *abucheo* se convirtió en *puchero*, algo muy habitual en el habla doméstica, sobre todo con niños. (Pienso, por ejemplo, en que mi mamá le decía *los sartenes* a los sostenes).

Comment: Es inevitable preguntar: ¿y con qué freía la comida? :)

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Mirando en el mapa de diccionarios he visto que el término _abuchear_ es relativamente reciente, sólo aparece en el DRAE desde 1992, y viene de "a" + "huchear", que significa "llamar a gritos" o "lanzar a los perros de caza dando voces", como indicas. Veo pues difícil que "abuchear" se transformara en "puchero", que es un término muchísimo más antiguo, aunque la acepción que tratamos sí podría venir de "huchear" o de "hucho".

Answer (score 2):

En el [Diccionario Español-Latín](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Archivos_de_la_BCRAE_Vocabulario_espnaol-latino_Nebrija.pdf) de Nebrija (1494) aparece la entrada

> Pucheros por buchetes. buca.

(en la pág. 174 del documento enlazado) por lo que me inclino a pensar que tiene su origen simplemente en una variante *juguetona* de [`buchetes`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6DF8Fuc), ya que el inflamiento de los carrillos suele formar parte del proceso de *hacer pucheros*.